# Inline dropdown positioning issue

Tags: drop-down-menu, inline

Please take a look at the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4LZnC/
I need to make it so when you hover on the `.dropdown` element, the `.expandable` to show but using the parent's background and border.
In other words, try removing `position:absolute` from `.expandable`. I need the same effect but without `.expandable` pushing the other content down. How do I achieve that? I really have no clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to assign position absolute to the parent element and wrap it with a fixed height container.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div class="dropdown">
        Flow content
        <div class="expandable">
        my expandable content here my expandable content here my expandable content   here my expandable content here my expandable content here 
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div.dropdown {background:red; border:3px solid blue; position:absolute; width: 100%;}
div.dropdown .expandable { display:none; position: relative; top:100%; left:0; }
div.dropdown:hover .expandable { display:block; }
#wrap{ height:26px; }
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/4LZnC/3/

Comment: Either I didn't expain it right or you didn't understand it. I need it to fit into parent's background and border, not create its own. `In other words, try removing position:absolute from .expandable. I need the same effect but without .expandable pushing the other content down.`